# Error Use of exit language construct is discouraged

Tags: magento2

Use of exit language construct is discouraged.

if ($attribute_name == $customerGroup) {
if ($dropdown_field > $Quantity) {

```
                    $this->messageManager->addError($this->helper->getGeneralConfig('minimum_alertmsg') . $dropdown_field);
                    $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart');
                 $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();
                 
                   Exit();
                }
            }
```

need to redirect in check out page without using exit(); and die();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Got The Solution

Using Javascript We Can Remove Error "Use of exit language construct is discouraged"

```
if ($attribute_name == $customerGroup) {
  if ($dropdown_field > $Quantity) {

    $this -> messageManager -> addError($this -> helper -> getGeneralConfig('minimum_alertmsg').$dropdown_field);
    $cartUrl = $this -> _url -> getUrl('checkout/cart');

    ?
    >
    <
    script type = "text/javascript" >
      window.location.href = "<?=  $cartUrl; ?> "; <
    /script>

    <
    ? php
  }
}
```